# Connect to db through TOAD when LDAP.ora does not exist and tnsnames.ora does not have the tns entry

Tags: toad, tnsnames

I was able to connect to TOAD using a db schema name that was not defined in my tnsnames.ora. I got the explanation here:
[TOAD connects despite the db name not being present in tnsnames.ora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890387/toad-connects-despite-the-db-name-not-being-present-in-tnsnames-ora/11891614#comment16110304_11891614)
But now, I need to give the db connection credentials to a peer and that developer does not have ldap.ora file in her /network/admin folder. How can she connect to  the db using TOAD?
I gave her my ldap.ora file and asked her to copy it in network/admin and then try. But that does nto seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the answer. On my machine I did a `tnsping <DB_NAME>` and that gave me the complete host name and port. Now the other developer can use these to create a tnsentry.